# C# 2010 is not loading delphi DLL

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, pinvoke

I am facing a problem. I have written and win32 DLL in delphi 2009. Now I want to dynamically load that DLL from C# desktop application but LoadLibray function returns 0. Here is CSharp code, please can any body helps me why DLL is not loading?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
  public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad, IntPtr hFile, uint dwFlag);

  [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
  public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procedureName);

  [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
  private extern static Boolean CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);


  public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
        ptr = LoadLibrary("MyDLL.dll", IntPtr.Zero, 0);

        if (ptr == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("DLL not laded");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Make sure your C# application is running in x86 mode.

Comment: Please check how to get those functions to report errors through the use of [GetLastError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx). Here you can probably just add this inside your if-statement: `throw new Win32Exception();` and see what happens.

Comment: Did you read the documentation of LoadLibrary? It describes how errors are handled.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Couldn't it be because user2724058 is invoking the LoadLibrary() API but with the LoadLibraryEx() parameter footprint? (I never did something like that so I am not sure.)

Comment: I did this many time with VC++ DLL loading in to the .NET and it works all the time. But I am getting the problem with the delphi win32 DLL

Comment: Do you disagree with what mg30org said, and what I wrote in my answer? Is there a good reason for neglecting error checking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you why that DLL is not loading as there is not enough information in the question.

**Hint**: Have you checked that your application is running in 32-bit or 64-bit appropriately for the DLL?

*However*, I can tell you how to get more information about the problem.

First, add the following to the attributes:

```
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
                         ^-----------------^
```

Then add this to your if-statement that handles the problem:

```
if (ptr == IntPtr.Zero)
    throw new Win32Exception();
```

This should give you a more specific exception message indicating what the problem might be.

Comment: C# application is compiled using x86 settings and Delphi DLL is in delphi 2009 that is 32 bit. My OS is windows 7 64 bit. I am just loading the library not loading any procedure of DLL. By debugging                                   Now it gives me following error on LoadLibrary function execution.   A call to PInvoke function'LoadLibrary' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature

Comment: That message is the runtime detecting the error that is described in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You have the wrong signature for `LoadLibrary`. It should be:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllname);
```

You had two spurious parameters and weren't capturing the error code.

Always check for errors when calling Win32 functions. In this case

```
IntPtr lib = LoadLibrary(dllname);
if (lib == IntPtr.Zero)
    throw new Win32Exception();
```

Common failure modes include:

- Mis-matched bitness.
- DLL not found on DLL search path.
- DLL's dependencies not resolved.

Comment: Exactly what I thought!